# Is there any solution to solve Asp.Net gridview row data transfer to some specific textboxs when clicking button in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am working with a grid-view which will be pop upped with data when user click on a specific button or element. In every row of the pop upped grid-view there is a column named "Action" which consist of a "Select Button". When user click on the select button on a specific row the data of the row will be appeared in some specific text box. But the problem is some rows are working fine but most of the rows are says "No Data Found". I used  j-Query here.

This is the gridView:

```
            <asp:GridView ID="showAllProductsGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" SortExpression="ProductName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="CategoryName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SubCategoryName" HeaderText="SubCategory" SortExpression="SubCategoryName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Barcode" HeaderText="Barcode" SortExpression="Barcode" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Cost" HeaderText="Cost" SortExpression="Cost" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductId" HeaderText="ProductId" SortExpression="ProductId" Visible="False" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryId" HeaderText="CategoryId" SortExpression="CategoryId" Visible="False" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SubCategoryId" HeaderText="SubCategoryId" SortExpression="SubCategoryId" Visible="False" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SalesPrice" HeaderText="Sales Price" SortExpression="SalesPrice" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="itemSelect" runat="server" Text="Select"  />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Here is the js code:

```
      $('body').on("click", "#ctl00_ViewContentPlace_btnItemSearch", function () {
                $('#main_div_item_search').delay().fadeIn();
            });

            $("#kv_close_item_search").click(function () {
                $('#main_div_item_search').fadeOut();
            });


            $('#ctl00_ViewContentPlace_showAllProductsGridView').find('[id*=itemSelect]').click(function () {
                var row = $(this).closest('tr');

                $('#main_div_item_search').fadeOut();

                $("#ctl00_ViewContentPlace_txtBarcode").val(row.find('td').eq(3).html());
                $("#ctl00_ViewContentPlace_ddlCategory").val(row.find('td').eq(6).html());
                $('#ctl00_ViewContentPlace_ddlSubcategory').val(row.find('td').eq(7).html());
                $('#ctl00_ViewContentPlace_ddlProduct').val(row.find('td').eq(5).html());




            });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to select the `aspx tags` based on **ids** and **classnames** etc. as they are server side and most of the attributes dynamically change.

the effective and easy way is to define input field `(run="server")` mean it must be a `aspx:input` Next define `onclick` even on each row of `gridview`. and inside that method get the required text of row and update to input text field.

This way you don't need to do complex hacks on `jquery` end.